# Looking for a good example of how fill form values from a live search

Tags: forms, search, live

I am trying to figure out the best method to implement a live search and populate form data with the result.  We have an existing asp.net website, c# with mssql data.  We have a table with about 40,000 records and I would like the users to be able to start typing a name and have the search start after maybe 3 letters and as the list builds they will find the record they want and at that time I'll go back to the data with the primary key and get the remaining detail columns for the item selected and fill a form.  My experience with ajax, json, linq and anything related is basic at best so I would like to at least know the right tool before I get lost in a rabbit hole.

So far I have not done any coding and just looked for examples but can't find anything specific to my situation.

If found an example, sort of.  The webservice page returns a list of names matching the search but I guess what I'm looking for is a name/value pair and a way to snag the selected pkey value to go get the detailed data.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Autocomplete txtAssetName

    $(function () {
        $('#<%= txtAssetName.ClientID %>').autocomplete(
            {
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../WebService.asmx/GetAssetNames",
                    data: "{ 'assetName': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) 
                    {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) 
                    {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request...  ' + result.responseJSON.Message);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 0
        });
    });



</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of your research so we know not to duplicate it?

Comment: If you would like to give the user an instant autocomplete experience you might want to consider using RediSearch.io suggest API, it has a native C# client see https://libraries.io/nuget/NRediSearch